# "java form generator" from a given wsdl file

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I'm trying to develop a form generator in java, in which users will be able to write a wsdl url and get the list of the operations supported by the web service in a ComboBox. When the user selects one of the items in ComboBox then he will see form fields generated using the wsdl url.

I'm a newbie in web service technologies, after searching about web service parsers on the net I decided to use axis library. But I really do not know which part of the wsdl document should I parse

I'm not trying to create java classes of the web service, I have to generate form fields for any wsdl url.

For instance here is a web service which provides 9 operations

http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx

and the wsdl file is here:

http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL

I need to know which parts of wsdl file should be parsed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A tool like that would be very useful, will you release it as an open source project?

Comment: this was a school project, I'm not sure if I can find it. Maybe I can write a new one, and you can be sure that if I write one, it will be published under GPL3 ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get started with WSDL and understand how such a document is structured, you should maybe have a look at some article like [Understanding WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx) or the [WSDL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/WSDL/default.asp) or any other beginner resource that you'll find on Google.

Now, to answer your question in a simplified way, you'll have to start with the `portType` element that contains:

> An abstract set of operations supported by one or more endpoints (commonly known as an interface); operations are defined by an exchange of messages

For example, in your case:

```
<wsdl:operation name="DictionaryList">
  <wsdl:documentation>Returns a list of available dictionaries</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:input message="tns:DictionaryListSoapIn"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:DictionaryListSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

And, for each operation, you'll need to parse the input and output messages, a `message` being:

> A definition of an abstract message that may consist of multiple parts, each part may be of a different type.

Here, for example the input message of the previous operation is:

```
<wsdl:message name="DictionaryListSoapIn">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DictionaryList"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Then, to understand the content of the message, have a look at the `types`:

> A container for abstract type definitions defined using XML Schema

Here, the `DictionaryList` element is defined as an empty compleType:

```
<s:element name="DictionaryList">
  <s:complexType/>
</s:element>
```

As I said, this is really a very simplified answer as WSDL can't be summarized in four paragraphs and, to be honest, what you are going to do is really not a trivial task. Let me rephrase this: **there will be blood!** So, even if these few lines may help you (a very little) to get started, I'd definitely not start such a project from scratch but rather use an existing library or tool (like [Xydra](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xydra/) or Eclipse [XML Forms Generator](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/xfg) or ...) that would allow to not reinvent the wheel.

By the way, I noticed that you have decided to use Axis and that you don't want to generate the Java classes but I'd warmly recommend to **not** use Axis anyway. Actually, I'd use JAX-WS RI wich is bundled in Java 6 and is a much easier API. Just in case, to generate the Java classes, just execute:

```
$ mkdir generated
$ wsimport -d generated http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL
```

Answer (score 3):

here is a good tutorial about "Reading a wsdl file" by Thomas Bayer
http://www.predic8.com/wsdl-reading.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial project, and you may find that a library that already does this would be your best approach, but places to start would be mapping attributes to HTML FORM components, and the Min/Max Occues to JavaScript events.

It would likely be a lot easier to write your FORM from your understanding of the WSDL.  As for something that could help, you could use something like

http://www.soapui.org/

Or for something web based (which I just tested with your WSDL and it works) you can try

http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html

I know that these two links might be totally off base for what you are trying to accomplish though, so good luck in your effort to tackle this challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the WSDL side, but you may consider [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org) for the form generation side: once you've extracted and parsed the WSDL, you can push it into Metawidget and get a lot of UI goodness for free (support for different platforms, different widget libraries, etc.)

Regards,

Richard.