# how to get parameter names of a method/operation from a wsdl file

Tags: java, wsdl, form-generator

I'm trying to develop a form generator from a given wsdl file in java.

Here is a post about the project: 
["java form generator" from a given wsdl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972110/java-form-generator-from-a-given-wsdl-file)

I could read operation names from wsdl file, and their bindings, but I need to get the parameters or arguments of a given operation from the wsdl in java. 

 Here is my current java code which I can read operation names and save them in an ArrayList:

 [http://pastebin.com/m570a6f76][2]

I really need help to get parameters of a given operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get the parameters you'll need to retrieve the message associated with each portType operation. The message references the types that are allowed as input and output from the inline (in the types section) or imported schemas. [WSDL4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/), which I think you're already using, provides a facility to retrieve the portType operation from the binding operation, the message from the portType operation, and read the inline and imported schemas in Java.